# OWA web access calendar view missing items

Tags: windows, exchange-2007, iphone, outlook-web-app

I have a user syncing calendar items - uses Outlook 2003, uses iPhone and uses OWA web access to view calendar....some recurring all day events are not showing up in OWA web access view, they are viewable in both iPhone and Outlook (client)....any ideas? ...Using Outlook Web Access version: 8.1.240.5 with Exchange Server 2007 Version: 08.01.0240.006

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts:

1. Try opening outlook on the machine using the following flags: /cleanviews /resetfolders (go to start>run and type outlook.exe /cleanviews /resetfolders). Allow this to sync back to the Exchange server before trying to see changes.
2. Try changing the sort order of the calendar entries in OWA. So you'd change to a different calendar view, then press "sort". I've seen a similar issue which ultimately was related to an SSL configuration issue on the Exchange server, but the indicator that this problem occurred was the ability to fix it by simply changing the sort order
3. Do you experience the problem in OWA in both Full and Light views? You can select this in IE, in other browsers you're forced to use the Light view so try the Full view in IE if you've been using a different browser.